# How does poky/meta/lib/oe/image.py get included when building core-image-minimal.bb?

Tags: python-2.7, yocto, bitbake, openembedded

I am using the Yocto Project, Jethro release. However, I think this question applies to other releases as well.

I need to modify the image creation process. I have read the BitBake manual, but I still don't know how a full python script or several scripts are included.

Here is what I have found so far:

```
bitbake core-image-mininmal
```

After bitbake reads all the config files and parses **bblayers.conf**, it searches all the layer directories for the recipe **core-image-minimal.bb**

In **core-image-minimal.bb**, we have:

```
inherit core-image
```

This inherits the class **core-image.bbclass** which in turn inherits **image.bbclass** which contains the bitbake code:

```
fakeroot python do_rootfs () {
    from oe.rootfs import create_rootfs
    from oe.image import create_image
    from oe.manifest import create_manifest

    # generate the initial manifest
    create_manifest(d)

    # generate rootfs
    create_rootfs(d)

    # generate final images
    create_image(d)
}
```

Searching the source tree for the text **create_image**, I found the following in **image.py**:

```
def create_image(d):
    Image(d).create()
```

and also:

```
def create(self):
    bb.note("###### Generate images #######")
    pre_process_cmds = self.d.getVar("IMAGE_PREPROCESS_COMMAND", True)
    post_process_cmds = self.d.getVar("IMAGE_POSTPROCESS_COMMAND", True)
```

I've also created my own class **my-class.bbclass** and put the following in it:

```
fakeroot python do_rootfs_prepend () {
    print("==> do_rootfs_prepend")
}

fakeroot python do_rootfs_append () {
    print("==> do_rootfs_append")
}
```

and I see the messages in the log file, so I know this is working to add my python code to the **do_rootfs** function in **image.bbclass**.

However, I would still like to know how **image.py** and a whole bunch of other *.py files are included (e.g. **rootfs.py**) from the **poky/meta/lib/oe** directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, note that rootfs/image code has been refactored quite a bit after the Jethro release: the last releases do not have some of the functions referred to in your example.

There's no Yocto-specific magic in the library function usage: they are used via standard python module import, just with meta/lib/ in the module search path, e.g.

```
from oe.image import create_image
```

will make the `create_image()` function from meta/lib/oe/image.py available in the current scope.